# Identity with exponential function: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2n}} = \frac{1}{e^2}$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Could you please explain me how we got this identity

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2n}} = \frac{1}{e^2}$

when we know

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e$

Thanks!

Comment: I think they literally just inverted it, then squared it: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=(\frac{n+1}{n})^n$ if you invert that and square it, you get $(\frac{n}{n+1})^{2n}$. Those operations preserve the limit I believe, so the result follows.

Comment: Tip: look at $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \cfrac{n+1}{n} \right)^{2n}$.

Comment: Thank you all for your work. Now I understand it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  } \frac { n^{ 2n } }{ (n+1)^{ 2n } } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ { \left( \frac { 1 }{ { \left( 1+\frac { 1 }{ n }  \right)  }^{ n } }  \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 1 }{ { e }^{ 2 } } $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint we can write it as $(\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})})^{2n}=\frac{1}{e^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{n^{2n}}{(n+1)^{2n}}$
divide top and bottom by $n^{2n}$

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac 1n)^{2n}} = \frac 1{e^2}$